# How to hide some records for a specific group in Odoo 15?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

Recently I asked a similar question ([How to hide a menuitem for a specific group in Odoo 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036889/how-to-hide-a-menuitem-for-a-specific-group-in-odoo-15)). The answer by Kenly was perfect, however, now I am looking for the same, but with rules.

I mean, I need to create a group whose users won't be able to see some records, regardless of the rest of the rules. Like a global rule, but for a specific group.

Example:

-Generate a group named for example *Hide customers*:

```
<record id="group_hide_customers" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Hide Customers</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden" />
</record>
```

-If you add an user to this group, the user will not able to see the contacts which are customers, regardless of the rest of the groups he belongs to. It doesn't matter if he belongs to `base.group_partner_manager`, he will only be able to see only non-customer contacts.

I was looking the modules in OCA `server-ux` repository, but it seems that there is no module for this functionality. I also took a look to the `base_menu_visibility_restriction` code, and then to `ir_rule.py` to see if something comes to my mind, with no results.

Any ideas? Basically I need a non-global rule which is added to the rest of the rules with AND instead of OR.